# query returns a toString() value?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to return the only value in a column by `querying` all values in the column and its not working.

Why does this `query` :

```
public String getDaily() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = smokinDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();       
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + smokinDBOpenHelper.MONEY_TABLE + " WHERE " + 
                KEY_PRICE, null);
    String s = ("" + cursor);       
    return s;
}
```

return this value `SQLiteCursor@4120eec8`

instead of the only value stored in that column which is `7.63` ?

Comment: You mean all the rows in the table have same KEY_PRICE value?

Comment: there's only ever one entry in the table

Comment: How many columns are there in the table?

Comment: There are 4 columns in the table

Comment: Your query should be "SELECT " + KEY_PRICE + " FROM " + smokinDBOpenHelper.MONEY_TABLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
String s = ("" + cursor);
```

To:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
String s = "" + cursor.getDouble("COLUMN_NAME"); // replace with your column name
```

It currently prints the `toString` value of `Cursor` because you're trying to concatenate an object of type `Cursor` to a `String`, when you should be concatenating an object of type `double` with type `String`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this instead.

```
String s = cursor.getString(0);
```